# Debugging an Application with Python & Node Processes In VS Code

Tags: python, node.js, visual-studio-code

I recently have picked up VS Code because I have a new component written in NodeJS that I need to be able to debug, and learned that debugging support was built in to VS Code. I have debugging possible in PyCharm for Python, but JS support is not available in PyCharm's community edition so I wanted to move my environment to VSC.

The application I am working with runs mainly on Python, and there is a new component that we've added that runs on NodeJS on a separate port. I have got my configuration set up to launch the main application, which spins up the Python and NodeJS servers.

Now, I would like to set it up to pause at my breakpoints when I set them in the NodeJS and Python code. I thought this could be done with the configuration with `"request": "attach"`, but when I match the port to my application's ports I only get an error (`Failed to attach (connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888)`). I know this is probably because the port is not running my app yet at this point, but when I go back to run the attach configuration by itself, I get a notification about how the process has terminated unexpectedly.

So here I am, I don't know what I need to do to get my breakpoints to stop so I can step through my Python and NodeJS code.

Here is my `launch.json` file. The Python process runs on port 8888 and the NodeJS process runs on port 8895.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "CloudDrafts",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/obrien.server/project/apps/obrien/runner.py",
            "args": ["-d", "${workspaceFolder}/obrien.server/_data"],
            "console": "externalTerminal",
            "pythonPath": "${workspaceFolder}/venv/bin/python2.7",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/obrien.server/project/apps/obrien",
            "env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/obrien.server/project"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach (Python)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 8888,
            "host": "localhost"
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach (Node.js)",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 8895,
            "address": "localhost"
        }
    ],
    "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "Debug CloudDrafts",
            "configurations": ["CloudDrafts", "Attach (Python)", "Attach (Node.js)"]
        }
    ]
}
```

To clarify, I have installed the Python extension, and have been through as much of Microsoft's documentation as I could find, but now I'm not really getting it and not having much luck finding what I need.

**What must be done to set up VS Code to allow for breakpoint debugging for an application running Python and NodeJS processes in separate ports?**

Answer (score 0):

The Python extension's debugger is only set up to debug Python code on both ends, so the error you are seeing in the `attach` scenario is because it's trying to find another instance of the `ptvsd` debugger on the other end and only finding Node. If you change to something like debugging by module or file then Python debugging will work again.

As for then attaching to a live Node process to debug the other side, I'm not sure how to do that.